# Comparing three clusters with only binary variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binary-data

I have three clusters of patients, and for each patient I have 189 binary variables which are diagnosis codes (0 indicates the patient doesn't have the diagnosis and 1 otherwise)

I want to perform comparisons between the three group and to examine if there are variables with significant difference scores between groups ( e.g if there is cluster/group with high proportion of specific diagnosis ). Which test should I use? if its chi square what is the expected value for each variable?

Comment: It sounds like you should be *exploring* and *characterizing* the clusters, not testing them.  To determine whether what you are seeing is real, you can cross-validate your procedure or, more simply, use your held-out data to see which hypotheses hold up.

Comment: Thank you I did some exploratory analysis  on the cluster and indeed they differ ( one cluster is sick and the other are healthy but they differ in Demographics

Answer (score 0):

For the general problem of comparing three proportions, see [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56300/which-test-to-use-to-compare-proportions-between-3-groups)

But, why do a test? It seems to me that if you want a cluster analysis, you don't want a test on the variables that went into the clustering. You want to look at the statistics that are output by the clustering procedure. The goal of a clustering procedure is to look at how the observations (here, patients) go together and, hopefully, to gain some insight, either on that specific question (e.g. "Huh! I knew that people who had A were likely to have B,  but I didn't know they were likely to have C." Or on other variables (e.g. "Huh! People who have A, B, and C are really likely to be XXX" where XXX is something other than the conditions, like a demographic variable.)

My intuition also says that this is a variation on the "Texas sharpshooter fallacy", where the guy shoots at a barn door and then paints bullseyes around the bullet holes.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I did clustering using Kernel PCA ( so the clustering was not directly on the observed variables)  and now I want to discover the characteristic of each cluster , I looked at 10 patients from each cluster and it seems to me that one cluster consists of healthy patients and the other clusters consists of sick patients. Now I want also to see which diagnosis go together with each other ( correlation between variables for each cluster which test is useful ?)  Chi square test is not helpful here ? ( it test if there is correlation between cluster status and diagnosis status)

Comment: Maybe choose a different clustering method that does use the observed variables? Most are designed to answer the exact question of which dx go together.

Comment: I got the best clustering metrics using Kernel PCA . Two clusters are sick and I want to discover how do they differ ( they have different variables correlation ? which diagnosis are dominant on each cluster ) what test can answer this question ( the Professor here at the Hebrew university  suggested chi square to see if cluster status depends on diagnosis status )